# Regex to insert dot (.) after characters, before new line

Tags: php, regex

I'm reformatting some text, and sometimes I have a string, where there is a sentence which is not ended by a dot.

I'm running various checks for this purpose, and one more I'd like is to **"Add dot after last character before new line"**.

I'm not sure how to form the regular expression for this:]

```
$string = preg_replace("/???/", ".\n", $string);
```

Comment: Give an example string

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
$string = preg_replace("/(?<![.])(?=[\n\r]|$)/", ".", $string);
```

negative lookbehind `(?<![.])` is checking previous character is not `.`

positive lookahead `(?=[\n\r]|$)` is checking next character is a newline or end of string.

Comment: How would you do this but using re.sub ?

    $string = preg_replace("/(?<![.])(?=[\n\r]|$)/", ".", $string);

Answer (score 1):

like this I suppose:

```
<?php
$string = "Add dot after last character before new line\n";
$string = preg_replace("/(.)$/", "$1.\n", $string);
print $string;
?>
```

This way the dot will be added after the word `line` in the sentence and before the `\n`.

demo : http://ideone.com/J4g7tH

Comment: Try with `$string = "before new line."`

Comment: This will add an extra `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
$string = "Add dot after last character before new line\n";
$string = preg_replace("/([^.\r\n])$/s", "$1.", $string);
```

Comment: Its nice. I think its handling empty line also.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, but none of them really caught all scenarios right.

I fumbled my way to a good solution using the word boundary regex character class:

```
// Add dot after every word boundary that is followed by a new line.
$string = preg_replace("/[\b][\n]/", ".\n", $string);
```

I guess `[\b][\n]` could just as well be `\b\n` without square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$content = preg_replace("/(\w+)(\n)/", "$1.$2", $content);
```

It will match a word immediately followed by a new line, and add a dot in between.

Will match: 
`Hello\n`

Will not match:
`Hello \n`
or
`Hello.\n`